# How would I calculate db column and display it in views in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, calculated-columns

I'm trying to calculate the values of a column for given user. I have a column in my "joblist" table that is named "jobprice" and I would like to calculate the total of the "jobprice" column value for current_user. I've tried few ideas I've had but they didn't work. I've gotten everything related already. Just need to figure out how to locate all user_id of current_user for "joblist" then take "jobprice" column value and sum up the total.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`sum()`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#sum):

```
current_user.joblists.sum('jobprice')
```

This assumes you have declared a `has_many :joblists` association in your `User` model.

Comment: That works but I'm getting a sum that is twice as much, any ideas why ?

Comment: twice as much as a database query?  or something else?  please clarify how you are calculating your 'correct' amount...

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot that I had calculations going on within the application controller and model, so grabbing the 'jobprice' directly from the DB was of course a lot more then what the final calculation comes out to be. I've fixed it though passing through the calculations also. Thank you!